# Qt4 Embeding external application inside QWidget

Tags: qt4

is it possible to run some application and display it inside QWidget (without window frame and buttons).

It would be greate if something like that could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't **think** it is possible - you would likely need to start a QProcess to get the application running, and that application likely would head straight to the window manager in order to get displayed (thus adding the window frame and buttons). It would be sweet to intercept the process's GUI requests and pipe them to your own widget, but as far as I know, unless you have the widget available in a library, you can't integrate it into your own.

Plus, you wouldn't really be able to interact with it beyond the means of [QProcess](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qprocess.html). Pretty cool concept though.